# Why this is coming in output ?> in php

Tags: php, html

wamp server 2.2E 
PHP Version 5.3.13 
I am using this code and i don't know why ?> is coming in my output
code :

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<p>my name is fahad</p>
<?php
// phpinfo();
$my_var1 =10;
$my_var2 =11;
echo $my_var1;
// print $my_var2;

?>

</body>
</html>
```

output :

```
my name is fahad

10 ?>
```

**p.s:**
i am using port 81 for php webserver and it is my complete code,even if i remove all my code then it again returns ?>

Thank you guys i have founded the mistake which was i accidently added extra ?> in the end and i didn't even paid attentions towards it

Comment: Are you sure it's interpreted by php?

Comment: You have an extra `?>` at the end of the file.

Comment: if it was not interpreted buy php, 10 would not show up

Comment: Give full version of your PHP and Server you are using

Comment: I just tried exactly what you have above and I didn't get the `?>` at the end.

Comment: @Baba WAMP 2.2E is based on PHP 5.3+

Comment: Please show your **complete** code

Comment: The port would have nothing to do with it by the way

Comment: Wild guess: Some "invisible" special character snuck into the ?> part? Remove it and type it again.

Comment: Strike that, you would get a parse error for </body>.

Comment: 'Accidently added extra ?> in the end' ,I'm glad you found it by yourself bcz I think none of us have thought about it :)

Comment: @dotNetSoldier Check my comment above :p

Comment: @HamZa DzCyberDeV yes you got it right the first time ,even he didn't posted the whole source code :)

Comment: guys why this noob kid (age: 14) is down voted ? ,I'm learning php and I do all kind of stupid things in it... :)

Comment: @dotNetSoldier Age has nothing to do with downvoting question.

Comment: @Charlie You are right ,but this was an acceptable question anyways,I have found SO to be a hard place for beginners...

Comment: @dotNetSoldier What makes SO different from other sites is that you need an actual question here, and be able to form a coherent question. I don't think it's necessarily hard on new programmers, just puts them at a higher standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have an extra `?>` at the end of PHP tag. Remove it.

Comment: Why is my answer negative 1 while it solves this question? -.-"

Comment: lolz sometimes when people wants to gain easily reputation they get downvoted. I mean what you have posted is not based on any evidence, so you should have put it as a comment. But wait someone already mentioned this in the comments. Anyways I'll give you a **1+** since you're new here.

Comment: Because this was already answered in the comments, and you only posted it as an answer to gain rep.

Comment: @HamZa DzCyberDeV,Lolz You should have posted your comment as answer... :)

Comment: @dotNetSoldier I won't feel good if I got 100rep for something like this :D

Comment: @ HamZa DzCyberDeV rep is kinda currency here ,So I wont mind :)